# Extract attribute value of parent node using php along with corresponding text values of child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I am dealing with large xml file that is heavily nested, and have decided to use XML reader due to the the large file. What I intend to extract are values of attribute "PartyID" from parent node (N8:Entity) and text values of "OrganisationName" and "CompanyID", and then export to csv.

From the my xml file, paths to this info are: 
     OrganisationName = 
     N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N2:OrganisationName/N2:NameElement 
     CompanyID = 
     N8:EntityList/N8:Entity/N5:Identifiers/N5:Identifier/N5:IdentifierElement.

I intend to have a table with this column headers: OrganisationName CompanyID PartyID. With my code, I am able to extract  OrganisationName and CompanyID, while column for PartyID is blank.

I have combed stackoverflow to know where the problem is but I could not find solution. I will be glad for help.

Below is my code.

```
<?php error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open("[MY XML FILE][1]");
$fo = fopen("companiesnzbn0.csv", "w" );
fputs($fo, "name, id, NZBN".PHP_EOL);
while ( $reader->read())    {
if ( $reader->name == 'N8:Entity' &&
        $reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT )    {
            $name = null;
            $id = null;
            $attrsPartyID = null;
            $newNode = $reader->expand();

            $nameNode = $newNode->getElementsByTagName('OrganisationName');
            if ( $nameNode->length > 0 ){
                $name = $nameNode[0]->getElementsByTagName('NameElement')-
 >item(0)->nodeValue;
            }

            $nzbNode = $newNode-
 >getElementsByTagName('UltimateHoldingCompany');

            foreach ($reader as $element) {
                $attrsPartyID = $element->getAttribute('PartyID');
            }

            $idNode = $newNode->getElementsByTagName('IdentifierElement');
            if ( $idNode->length > 0 ){
                $id = $idNode[0]->nodeValue;
            }

            $newName = str_ireplace(","," ",$name);

            fputs($fo,  $newName.",".$id.",".$attrsPartyID.PHP_EOL);

        }
 }
 fclose($fo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 error_reporting ( E_ALL );
 ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );
 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);

 $reader = new XMLReader();

 $reader->open("my.xml");
 $fo = fopen("my.csv", "w" );
 fputs($fo, "name, id, NZBN".PHP_EOL);
 while ( $reader->read())    {


 if ( $reader->name == 'N8:Entity' &&
        $reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->localName == 
 'Entity')    {
            $name = null;
            $id = null;
            $attrsPartyID = null;
            $newNode = $reader->expand();

            $nameNode = $newNode->getElementsByTagName('OrganisationName');
            if ( $nameNode->length > 0 ){
                $name = $nameNode[0]->getElementsByTagName('NameElement')-
  >item(0)->nodeValue;
            }


            $attrsPartyID = (string)$reader->getAttribute('PartyID');


            $idNode = $newNode->getElementsByTagName('IdentifierElement');
            if ( $idNode->length > 0 ){
                $id = $idNode[0]->nodeValue;
            }

            $newName = str_ireplace(","," ",$name);

            fputs($fo,  $newName.",".$id.",".$attrsPartyID.PHP_EOL);

        }
 }
 fclose($fo);
```